# Random function does not return random values

Tags: rust, random

If I generate 10 random numbers this way, it works (it produces different values)

```rust
fn main() {
    let seed = std::time::SystemTime::now()
        .duration_since(std::time::UNIX_EPOCH)
        .expect("system time cannot be before unix epoch")
        .as_millis() as u64;

    let mut rng = oorandom::Rand32::new(seed);

    for _ in 0..10 {
        println!("Your random number is: {}", &rng.rand_range(0..4));
    }
```

But if I factor them into a struct, the generated values are always the same:

```
use oorandom::{self, Rand32};

struct Util {
    rng: Rand32,
}
impl Util {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let seed = std::time::SystemTime::now()
            .duration_since(std::time::UNIX_EPOCH)
            .unwrap()
            .as_millis() as u64;
        println!("new color util {}", seed);
        let rng = Rand32::new(seed);
        Util { rng }
    }
    pub fn get_random(&self) -> u32 {
        let mut rng = self.rng;
        let random_number = rng.rand_range(0..4);
        random_number
    }
}

fn main() {
    let util = Util::new();
    for _ in 0..10 {
        println!("Your random number is: {}", util.get_random());
    }
}
```

What is the difference between those two ways to use the `get_random` API, and why does it break when I put `rng` in a struct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't work because you are copying `rng` out of the struct, then mutating it (registering that you have sampled a number):

```rust
impl Util {
    pub fn get_random(&self) -> u32 {
        let mut rng = self.rng;  // <-- here you copy `rng`,
                                 // creating a new value, unrelated with `self.rng`
        let random_number = rng.rand_range(0..4); // <-- here you mutate `rng`,
        random_number                             // but leave `self.rng` untouched
    }
}
```

Instead, you must take a *mutable borrow* to `self` to be able to mutate `rng` in place:

```rust
impl Util {
    pub fn get_random(&mut self) -> u32 {
        //             +++ `mut` has been added, to allow mutation of `self`
        let rng = &mut self.rng;  // this does not copy `self.rng`
        let random_number = rng.rand_range(0..4);
        random_number
    }
}
```

Or, more shortly

```rust
impl Util {
    pub fn get_random(&mut self) -> u32 {
        let random_number = self.rng.rand_range(0..4);
        random_number
    }
}
```

Or even

```rust
impl Util {
    pub fn get_random(&mut self) -> u32 {
        self.rng.rand_range(0..4)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this confusion!

Comment: This is the reason why (contrary to what the official Rust recommendation is) I'm not a huge fan of slapping `#[derive(Copy)]` on absolutely every struct that can accept it ...

Comment: @Finomnis yeah, I was surprised too at first that you could even copy this opaque structure that carries a non-trivial inner state. If `Copy` is not an auto trait for every eligible type, it's exactly because there are situations like these where it doesn't make sense to implement it.

Comment: Also, `oorandom` has no proper way of contributing (no github), it has [open unanswered bug reports](https://todo.sr.ht/~icefox/oorandom/7), and doesn't even implement [rand_core](https://docs.rs/rand_core/). @Magin I think it would be wise in general to replace it with [`rand_pcg`](https://docs.rs/rand_pcg/). I don't understand why `oorandom` got so big, but in my opinion, it didn't deserve it. It has a nice homepage, maybe that's why.

Comment: Thank you @Finomnis ! I'm also wondering why I can't find more information about `oorandom` on google. I will try `rand_pcg` in my project!

Comment: @Magin It's a little bit more complicated because it uses the `rand_core` traits for consistency, which means some of the functionality requires the `RandCore` or `SeedableRng` trait. But then, you should be able to use for example `Pcg32::seed_from_u64` to initialize it, and all the `RandCore` functions to get randomness out of it.